# Design pattern name : One Big method converted to a Class

Tags: design-patterns

What is the name of the design pattern (defined by Kent Beck I think) where a big method in one class is refactored in a new separate class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the pattern is called **Extract class**.

Comment: Hmm, I distinctly remember that it had method in its name but can't find it in any of my books :(

Comment: @Nikola Stjelja: it's a [refactoring technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring), and I believe the correct name is **Extract class**. There's also **Extract method**, but that usually means breaking a large method into smaller ones into the same class.

Answer (score 0):

The result of that Refactoring would be an example of the Command pattern.